# Checkbox not clearing after click event

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, telerik

I have a click event that I run when someone selects a checkbox. I have provided my code below as a reference. The checkbox does not clear after the user selects OK. I clearly set the property to false in the code, and I used breakpoint to make sure it was getting to that point and it was. I even made sure my checkbox was receiving false and it was. What is preventing me from unchecking that box and how should I go about fixing this problem?

```
private void rChkBoxB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text) > 256)
    {
        DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("B does not support numbering over a number!", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            rChkBoxB.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any event to `CheckboxChanged` attached?

Comment: Try using `rChkBoxB.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;`

Comment: @Tijesunimi Telerik does not support CheckState.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos Ok,Why not add the telerik tag?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try executing this code on MouseUp instead of Click